# How do I have one drop down list's choices determine the choices available in another drop down list?

Tags: jquery

It works initially, but chooses all choices and not the appropriate ones. My jQuery chooses both baseball and football option values at once. Can someone help me fix it?

**HTML**

```
<div class="formControl">
    <label>Sport</label>
    <select id="sport">
        <option value="">--Select--</option>
        <option value="football">Football</option>
        <option value="baseball">Baseball</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="formControl">
    <label>Equipment</label>
    <select id="equipment">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="football">Helmet</option>
        <option value="football">Pads</option>
        <option value="baseball">Bat</option>
        <option value="baseball">Gloves</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$("#sport").change(function(){
    $("#equipment").val($(this).val());
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this would be to have 2 different `<select>` lists and show the active one.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9AL2D/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="formControl">
    <label>Sport</label>
    <select id="sport">
        <option value="">--Select--</option>
        <option value="football">Football</option>
        <option value="baseball">Baseball</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="formControl">
    <div id="football" class="equipment">
        <label>Equipment</label>
        <select id="football-equipment">
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value="football">Helmet</option>
            <option value="football">Pads</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div id="baseball" class="equipment">
        <label>Equipment</label>
        <select id="baseball-equipment">
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value="baseball">Bat</option>
            <option value="baseball">Gloves</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(function () {
    $('.equipment').hide();
});

$("#sport").change(function () {
    var val = $(this).val();
    $('.equipment').hide();
    $('#' + val).show();
});
```

Comment: Beautiful. Love how you had the hide equipment before choosing. upvote most definitly